# RegExp to match dot but not i.e or e.g

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like the match the third dot in this string

"Test i.e and some more e.g. And"

So, find the first dot that isn't "i.e" or "e.g"

So far, I have

```
(?!i\.e|e\.g)(\.)
```

But it still seems to be capturing all dots

Comment: [`\..*?\..*?(\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/lI2jA5/1)

Comment: \.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*(\.)

Comment: Updated example text

Comment: A real solution depends on whether you are extracting or replacing the dots, and whether you have access to JS code or not.

Comment: @Cuel If you have any problems with the accepted answer solutions, please precise the question and let know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the accepted answer was good enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different ideas...

1.) To match dot at a non-[word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
\.\B
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tK2jB4/2)

---

2.) Or if it is always the very last character, just use end [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
\.$
```

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iJ7wY9/1)

---

3.) But if you want to match the last dot with characters ahead, use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
\.(?![^.]*\.)
```

At any dot looks if not another dot is ahead (with any amount of `[^.]*` *non-dots* in between).

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uK1sN7/2)

Comment: The first solution with not capture .m, the second solution will only match the last dot, and I don't think that the third solution has to do anything with the op. But good review though !

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not support look-behinds, this will be a hard task to do with the language. If you ask me, I would suggest traversing the text stream yourself and getting the dots, this is very simple to do and would probably be a lot faster than regexps.